Implicit casts in Java (passing value type wrappers to methods expecting a regular Integer or Long)
It has become pretty common in some OOP languages to benefit from the best of both worlds :

The best of value-type objects (in Java that would be @Value (Lombok), or more recently just record) to avoid "primitive obsession" and pass around simple value wrappers. We can get the added benefit of potentially doing some extra validation in their constructor, but the core capability is the direct value comparison of two different objects.
The best of implicit type conversions (for example if your value type is a wrapper around an Integer, then you can still pass it wherever an Integer is expected by some already-written method )

in C#, nowadays point 2 is easy to achieve with implicit and similar techniques. But I wouldn't know how to do it in Java, as one cannot inherit custom classes from native classes Integer or Long.
An example :
// This is technically not an Integer, but a value type object (record)
public record PositiveInteger(Integer value) {
    public PositiveInteger{
        if (value < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

...

// This expects an Integer. I should not be able to pass a PositiveInteger
public static printInteger(final Integer someInteger) {
   print(someInteger.toString());
}

...

public static void main() {
  Integer i = 1234;
  printInteger(i);

  PositiveInteger x = new PositiveInteger(6789);
  printInteger(x);  // <-- the hard part: effortless conversion 
                           from my custom type to Integer, 
                           without having to change the printInteger method
}

How do you get as close to this as possible in Java? the ultimate goal is to pass around PositiveInteger values with as little hassle as possible, as if they were simply Integers.

What do you mean by ass around PositiveInteger values with as little hassle as possible? Any object could be a method parameter.

@menteith see the example I provided ("THE HARD PART"), and see the end of the sentence "AS IF THEY WERE SIMPLY INTEGERS"

@jeancallisti If you're going to be like that, see your own "ONE CANNOT INHERIT THE CUSTOM CLASSES FROM NATIVE CLASSES". You answered your own question. There's nothing to do. Your example is pretty bad, so perhaps you should have some patience with those who read it: Your method is called printNumber but takes an Integer (instead of the very much extendible, non-final j.l.Number), and 'print me' is available as toString() in j.l.Object itself. Your 'point' is fair enough (other code might demand an integer where you want a positive integer). Your example is not illuminative, though.

Point 2 is not possible in Java.  A good thing, too, the example you give looks confusing to use.

You could extend Number, but it will not bring you that much.

The "bad" example I gave is exactly how it's been done successfully in C# for several years, and it hasn't been confusing anyone. As always in Java: Either "it can't be done" or "it's dumb to do it". I guess I will close this question but let me enlighten you people : https://youtu.be/tgPTQ-ST8qQ?feature=shared&t=244

“in Java that would be @Value”  It would?  Where is this Value annotation type defined?  Not in Java SE, as far as I know.  If some third party is doing that, that’s neat, but that’s not Java—that’s a tool based on Java.

@VGR I believe they are referring to the Lombok annotation.

You cannot extend Integer because it is final, I don't know why you're calling it a native class. How would a program know that it should use a specific field to conform to a method signature? You could always have something like 'printInteger(Supplier sup)' Then you can easily make an object conform to that. Such as a method reference.

@matt "Supplier" is a good lead.

General

How do you get as close to this as possible in Java? the ultimate goal is to pass around PositiveInteger values with as little hassle as possible, as if they were simply Integers.

But they cannot behave as if they were Integers because, as you are aware, Integer is final.  All objects of type Integer have class Integer.  This was an intentional design decision, and it is unlikely to be relaxed.  Furthermore, Java autoboxing works only with the standard primitive-type wrapper classes, so if you pass around values of type PositiveInteger then you'll need to invoke a method or read a field to get at the wrapped int.  I guess one could hope for some movement on that side, but I wouldn't hold my breath.
"As close as possible" depends on how you judge.  For example,

if autoboxing is a requirement then you really have only one alternative in the language and standard library itself: use java.lang.Integer (or one of the other standard wrapper classes).

for "close" in a class hierarchy sense, with your own PositiveInteger class, you can write that as a subclass of java.lang.Number.  The wrapped int value would be provided by its intValue() method, and you could provide a method to convert directly to Integer, too, if you wanted to do.  This would not get you autoboxing, but it would get you some interoperability that you would not have otherwise.  Your class can be immutable, of course.

for PositiveInteger as a record class, you've pretty much already chosen all the relevant characteristics.  You get a class that does not support autoboxing, and whose closest common ancestor with Integer is Object.


Side note: @Value
There is no such annotation in the Java standard library.  Maybe you mean Lombok's @Value annotation, which can have an effect similar to using a record class when combined with an annotation processor that supports it.  Or maybe some other third-party annotation.  Any way around, that would be a third-party add-on, not part of Java proper.
There is a concept of "value classes" in the process of being introduced into Java, in Project Valhalla. But this is primarily about object (lack of) identity, not about autoboxingt.  The plan appears to be to, eventually, convert the standard wrapper classes into value classes, but that will not help you.
Side note: Bean Validation API
Jakarta EE (formerly Java EE) offers Jakarta Validation, formerly known as Bean Validation. This technology provides, among other things, annotations by which you could express constraints such as the basic one of your PositiveInteger class.  Supposing that you were working in an environment where this API is available, you could get some of what you want by applying appropriate annotations, such as @Min.
@Min(0)
int countGuests;


I think they are referring to Lombok @Value? It treats a class as an immutable type similar to a native record.

You're probably right, @Mr.Polywhirl. I have revised my comments accordingly.

Yes I was referring to Lombok. Thank you for this through answer which explores possibilities @JohnBollinger . I mark it as the accepted answer.

@JohnBollinger the Supplier<Integer> lead suggested by @matt in the comments of the question is also a good idea.

@jeancallisti, yes, and that's a special case of some of the ideas already discussed in this answer. But I don't think it speaks directly to the question posed, so I'm satisfied with its existing coverage in comments.

To recap other answers and comments :
1) It's not possible as-is, there is no implicit cast mechanism in Java (apart from the built-in ones, for example when concatenating a String and an Integer with the + operator )
2) The closest workaround would be to use Supplier<Integer> or IntSupplier in place of Integer.

Supplier example
public record CustomIntegerWrapper(int value) 
              implements Supplier<Integer> // <-- !!!
{

    public CustomIntegerWrapper {
    
    ...
    
    // Implements interface Supplier
    public @NotNull Integer get() {
        return value;
    }
}

public void printInteger(Integer i) {
   System.out.println(i);
}

...

Integer i = 123;
printInteger(i);

Supplier<Integer> x = new CustomIntegerWrapper(123);
printInteger(x.get());


IntSupplier example
public record CustomIntegerWrapper(int value) 
              implements IntSupplier // <-- !!!
{

    public CustomIntegerWrapper {
    
    ...
    
    // Implements interface Supplier
    public @NotNull int getAsInt() {
        return value;
    }
}

public void printIntSupplier(IntSupplier i) {
   System.out.println(i.getAsInt());
}

...

Integer i = 123;
printIntSupplier(() -> { return i; });

IntSupplier x = new CustomIntegerWrapper(i);
printIntSupplier(x);

Note: If you change printIntSupplier as follows :
public void printIntSupplier(IntSupplier i) {
   System.out.println(i); // no more .getAsInt()
}


then printing will give you
CustomIntegerWrapper[value=123]
Not necessarily what we want but still readable, for example in logs.
